# What is the meaning of id?

Tags: objective-c, types

I am (trying to) learn Objective-C and I keep coming across a phrase like:

```
-(id) init;
```

And I understand `id` is an Objective C language keyword, but what does it mean to say "the compiler specifically treats `id` in terms of the pointer type conversion rules"?

Does `id` automatically designate the object to its right as a pointer?

Comment: It's the opposite of the ego.  For some people that's `void*`

Comment: Here is a discussion relevant to the question: [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id/14652187#14652187)

Comment: Maybe you're here because [nobody told you about iD](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Doom_music)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`id` is a pointer to any type, but unlike `void *` it always points to an Objective-C object. For example, you can add anything of type `id` to an NSArray, but those objects must respond to `retain` and `release`.

The compiler is totally happy for you to implicitly cast any object to `id`, and for you to cast `id` to any object. This is unlike any other implicit casting in Objective-C, and is the basis for most container types in Cocoa.

Comment: Supplement: `id `'s definition is `typedef struct objc_object *id;` , so it pointer to a `Objc` object.

Comment: is it the same as `NSObject`? means, can i replace `id` with `NSObject` when it's a return type?

Comment: Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/id?language=objc

Comment: @ThunderWiring - A precise answer would be NO, since you could assign an NSProxy to a variable typed as an id. (NSProxy does not descend from NSObject.)

Answer (score 35):

`id` is a pointer to any Objective-C object (`objc_object`). It is not just a void pointer and you should not treat it as so. It references an object that should have a valid `isa` pointer. The values that can be stored in `id` are also not just limited to `NSObject` and its descendants, which starts to make sense of the existence of the `NSObject` protocol as well as the [`NSProxy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class which does not even inherit from `NSObject`. The compiler will allow you to assign an object referenced by type `id` to any object type, assign any object type to `id`, as well as send it any message (that the compiler has seen) without warning.

Answer (score 31):

`id` is a generic type. This means that the compiler will expect *any* **object** type there, and will not enforce restrictions. It can be useful if you're expecting to use more than one class of objects there; you can then use introspection to find out which class it is. `id` automatically assumes a pointer, as all objects in Objective-C are passed as pointers/references.

**Some Additional Resources:**

[*id vs NSObject* vs id*](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html)
[*Objective-C Programming (Wikibooks)*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/in_depth#The_id_type)
[*Introspection*](http://cupsofcocoa.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/objects-part-5-introspection/)
[*Dynamic Typing*](http://cupsofcocoa.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/objects-part-6-dynamic-typing/)

Comment: The first blog link is now dead, but can be found at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110724104417/http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html), the last two links now seem to redirect to a suspicious looking site, please replace them with archive.org links: [Introspection](https://web.archive.org/web/20120622135114/http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/02/13/objects-part-5-introspection/), [Dynamic Typing](https://web.archive.org/web/20120706231341/http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/02/20/objects-part-6-dynamic-typing/)

Comment: Last two links were to my old blog … I used to have the domain for it  Just updated the links to their current Wordpress subdomain

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you edit the first link as well? It's still dead. An archive.org link is better than nothing, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

- **id** is a data type of object identifiers in Objective-C, which can
  be use for an object of any type no matter what class does it have.
  **id** is the final super type of all objects.

**In java or c# we use like this**

```
 Object data = someValue;


 String name =(Object)data;
```

**but in objective c**

```
id data= someValue;



NSString *name= data;
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. It's true that having `id x` designates x as a pointer, but saying that the pointer type conversion rules apply is wrong, because "id" has special type conversion rules. For example, with a `void *` pointer you can't do this:

```
void *x;
char *y = x; // error, this needs an explicit cast
```

On the contrary, it's possible with id:

```
id x;
NSString *y = x;
```

See more usage of type [id in objective c examples](http://dobegin.com/objc-id-type/).

In addition in the "modern" Objective C it's preferred to use `instancetype` instead of "id" on "init" methods. There's even an automatic conversion tool in Xcode for changing that.
Read about instancetype: [Would it be beneficial to begin using instancetype instead of id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id)