# Constructor asking for a return type

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, object, constructor

To begin, i'm not very comfortable with Objective c, i'm trying to convert a C++ class into an  Objective C and i'm having trouble with the implementation on  my class this is what i got for c++

```
UniqueWord::UniqueWord(const string word, const int line)
{
wordCatalog=word;
count = 0;
addLine(line);
}

//Deconstructor.
UniqueWord::~UniqueWord(void)
{
}
```

and this is what i got for Objective C

```
@implementation UniqueWord

-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str andline:(NSInteger)line{
    _wordCatalog=str;
    count=0;
    addline(line);
    return ?//return what? it states (Control reaches end of non-void function)
}
```

I'm really new to classes in objective c, so i'm also asking for a dumbed down answer to,What in the world is an "id" and how do you use it?

Comment: Follow this link for an explanation of what id is: [So question on id meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7987060/35499)

Comment: Note that constructors in C++ do have a return type; according to the language standard, it's the name that they do not have.

Comment: When declaring init methods the preferred return type should be `instancetype` rather than `id` to support type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective C constructors a little bit different. You should create something like following:

```
-(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString*)str andline:(NSInteger)line{
    self = [super init];
    if(self == nil) return nil;
    _wordCatalog=str;
    count=0;
    addline(line);
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a generic class in Objective-C. This is somewhat similar to `void*` of C++, but with a lot more support from the execution environment so as to not require much typecasting.

There is no parallel concept in C++: an untyped object reference lets you use objects dynamically, with the specifics of the call checked at runtime, rather than at compile time.

Also note that Objective-C uses initializers instead of constructors. The two serve similar purposes, but are not the same: constructors can operate either together with operator `new` or separately from it, while initializers can operate only with the method that does allocation. Additionally, an initializer can return a different object in place of the one provided by `alloc`; constructors cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

An `id` is a point to any object in Objective-C. An init method returns an allocated and instantiated object. I would refer you to the Apple docs regarding initializers at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

In using what the article above says you'll want to write something like.

```
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)str andLine:(NSInteger)line {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _wordCatalog = str;
    }
    return self;
```

Comment: Edited to showcase that feature.

Answer (score 0):

The typical form (which you should use) for init methods is like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ( (self = [super init] ) )
    {
        [other code you want in the constructor]
    }

    return self;
}
```

So for the method you have, it should look something like this:

```
-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str andline:(NSInteger)line{

    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        _wordCatalog=str;
        count=0;
        addline(line);
    }

    return self;
}
```

That is, unless the super class has an initWithString:andline: constructor, in which case you would use

```
if ( (self = [super initWithString:string andline:line) )
```

as the if statement.

Comment: When declaring `init` methods the preferred return type should be `instancetype` rather than `id` to support type checking.

Comment: @Zaph: for instance methods whose names start with `init`, the compiler already assumes the return type is `instancetype`

Comment: @newacct Yes and what is the value/advantage in specifying `id` rather than `instancetype ` in that case?