# How to convert the nsstring format to json response format in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

My Json Response:

```
{
"xxx": {
"y": {
"id": 1,
"name": "z"
},
"startday": "2016-01-10",
"status": "New",
"total": 1,
"a": [
{
"id": 766,
"b": {
"id": 3,
"name": "c"
},
"d": {
"id": 4
 },
"e": {
"id": 1,
"name": "f"
},
"g": {
"id": 8,
"name": "h"
},
"hours": 1,
"comments": "",
"spent_on": "2016-01-10"
}
]
}
}
```

From this i created a string like this:

```
 NSString * str = @"{\"xxx\":{\"y\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"z\"},\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\",\"status\":\"New\",\"total\":1.0,\"a\":[{\"id\":766,\"b\":{\"id\\":3,\\"name\\":\\"c\\"},\\"d\\":{\\"id\\":4},\\"e\\":{\\"id\\":1,\\"name\\":\\"f\\"},\\"g\\":{\\"id\\":8,\\"name\\":\\"h\\"},\\"hours\\":1.0,\\"comments\\":\\"\\",\\"spent_on\\":\\"2016-01-10\\"}]}}";
```

Then I post this value by below code:

```
NSData *objectData = [str  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

if (jsonError == NULL)

{

msgView =@"error msg null";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData *requestData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

}
```

It hits server and gets the response.similarly, I get all the values user entering the app.I create the NSstring with concatenation.

```
NSString* concate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@,%@%@%@,%@,%@%@,%@%,%@,%@,%@%@%@%@%@%@,%@%@,%@%@,%@%@",xx,....];
```

so i get output response like this after concatenate:

```
{\"x\":{\"y\":{\"id\":1,
\"name\":\"a\"
},
\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\"
,
\"status\":\"New\"
,{\"total\":1,\"time_entries\":[{\"id\":766,
\"b\":{
\"id\":8,
\"name\":\"c\"
}
,
\"u\":{
\"id\":22
}
,\"d\":{\"id\":1
\"name\":\"e\"
},
\"l\":{
\"id\":8,
\"name\":\"g\"
}
,\"hours\":1,\"comments\":\"\",\"spent_on\":\"2016-01-12\"}]}}
```

So if pass this, it throws error.here i have to concatenate or combined different strings with other approach.or is there any possibilities to convert string to json response format.or else any other simple way to do this task.please suggest me ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to convert your `NSString` to `NSData` by doing the following

```
NSData *data = [concate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then simply use the `JSONObjectWithData:` method of `NSJSONSerialization` to convert it to JSON

```
NSError *error = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if(!error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert you `NSString` to `NSData`

```
NSString * str = @"{\"xxx\":{\"y\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"z\"},\"startday\":\"2016-01-10\",\"status\":\"New\",\"total\":1.0,\"a\":[{\"id\":766,\"b\":{\"id\\":3,\\"name\\":\\"c\\"},\\"d\\":{\\"id\\":4},\\"e\\":{\\"id\\":1,\\"name\\":\\"f\\"},\\"g\\":{\\"id\\":8,\\"name\\":\\"h\\"},\\"hours\\":1.0,\\"comments\\":\\"\\",\\"spent_on\\":\\"2016-01-10\\"}]}}";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now, this `NSData` is converted to [`id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987060/what-is-the-meaning-of-id) using `NSJSONSerialization`

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Here, you have your json data

```
NSLog(@"%@",json);
```