# What's going on in NSCFBoolean and NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, boolean

Ok, so I have an NSDictionary that holds a boolean value. It's loaded from the server and parsed by the framework, and for some reason it ends up being stored as an NSCFBoolean in the dictionary (don't ask,  all I know is that the -class method returns __NSCFBoolean).

Since NSCFBoolean is a framework-private **class** that I cannot use directly, I make a reference to it:

```
id myBool = myDict[@"my_bool"];
```

Now comes the cool part: evaluating it. I used a breakpoint and the "po" command. These are the results:

```
> po myBool
0

> po [myBool class]
__NSCFBoolean

> po [myBool boolValue]
<nil>
```

What the..?

```
> po myBool == true
false

> po myBool == false
<nil>
```

*brain melts*

How is it possible that *== true* returns *false* and *== false* returns *nil*?

I have a number of years of experience in programming in Objective-C but I have never seen this weird behaviour before! I've read several articles about the differences between the different boolean types and their behaviours and quirks ([This article at NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/bool/) is quite interesting) but I've read nothing that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: Most of the confusion is caused by the fact that the compiler treats `myBool` as `id` (void pointer) although `[myBool class]` prints `__NSCFBoolean`. For example this explains `[myBool boolValue]` == `nil` because `id` has no method `boolValue`.

Comment: And `> p [myBool boolValue]` returns what? Be careful with `po`, since it's object, if it' 0, often it prints nil instead of false or 0 as you expect, use `p` when it's the case for check.

Comment: `__NSCFBoolean` is returned from `@NO`, `@YES`, `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` and `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.

Comment: @Vadian [id](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/id) is not the same as void pointer, see [What is the meaning of id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987060/what-is-the-meaning-of-id). `[myBool boolValue]` will send selector `boolValue` to `myBool`, how `myBool` is declared doesn't matter. The superclass of `__NSCFBoolean` is `NSNumber` and `[myBool boolValue]` == `nil` because `[myBool boolValue]` returns `NO` which `po` (print object) will print as `<nil>`.